# jquery when adding of two numbers

Tags: jquery

here is my code in which i am having two inputs with min value -2 and max value is 10 and total in div. when the value entered is -2 it must treat as zero and total must be zero. In remaining cases it is sum of the two number. when i entered -2 it the first input it was showing total as zero. but when i entered -2 in the next input also the sum is showing -2 instead of zero. Please check it.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">      </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#a,#b').keyup(function(){

         var a=$('#a').val();
         var b=$('#b').val();

          if(a==-2)
          {
            a=0;
          }
          else if(b==-2)
          {
            b=0;
          }
          else
          {
          }

           var tot=(+a)+(+b);

           $('#tot').html(tot);

      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" name="a" id="a" min="-2" max="10" />
    <input type="number" name="b" id="b" min="-2" max="10" />
    <div id="tot"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small error in your code: the  `else if(b==-2)` should just be  `if(b==-2)`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">      </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#a,#b').keyup(function(){

         var a=$('#a').val();
         var b=$('#b').val();

          if(a==-2)
          {
            a=0;
          }
          if(b==-2)
          {
            b=0;
          }


           var tot=(+a)+(+b);

           $('#tot').html(tot);

      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" name="a" id="a" min="-2" max="10" />
    <input type="number" name="b" id="b" min="-2" max="10" />
    <div id="tot"></div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your else statement then it should do as you want.

Change:

```
else if (b == -2) {
  b = 0;
}
```

To:

```
if (b == -2) {
  b = 0;
}
```

Problem is that you never hit the else statement if your a == -2

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#a,#b').keyup(function() {

    var a = $('#a').val();
    var b = $('#b').val();

    if (a == -2) {
      a = 0;
    }
    if (b == -2) {
      b = 0;
    } else {}

    var tot = (+a) + (+b);

    $('#tot').html(tot);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="a" id="a" min="-2" max="10" />
<input type="number" name="b" id="b" min="-2" max="10" />
<div id="tot"></div>
```